# SQL.Working with views

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, triggers

I have a table 'Goods' with different information about goods (name, price, etc). I need to create a view at the same scheme as table 'Goods' has. But the view must be empty. And when user adds new good to the view it is saved in table 'Goods', but the view remains empty when user opens it next time. So main idea is not to show existing data to the user which has access to the view.

Comment: View can be empty only if correlated table(s) is(are) empty

Comment: Why not just grant them `INSERT` rights but not grant them `SELECT`, on the table itself, and be done with it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I thought about it, but this is my task, I can't change. What should I use? Delete after insert trigger?

Comment: What database system are you working in (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc)? Please edit your tags and add that as one of them. This is going to be RDBMS specific.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your on a database system that supports a concept like SQL Server's [`CHECK OPTION`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), and you're allowed to create a view that *doesn't* have that option set, you should be fine:

```
create table T (ID int not null)
go
create view V
as
    select * from T where 1=0
go
select * from V
go
insert into V(ID) values (10)
go
select * from V
go
select * from T
```

The two selects from `V` return 0 rows. The select from `T` returns one row:

```
ID
----
10
```

`CHECK OPTION`:

> Forces all data modification statements executed against the view to follow the criteria set within select_statement. When a row is modified through a view, the WITH CHECK OPTION makes sure the data remains visible through the view after the modification is committed.

And you want the opposite - you want to allow data modifications performed through the view to create rows which are *invisible* through the view.

Answer (score 1):

Create table Goods1 with "insert trigger" on it which make insert into Goods and delete from Goods1

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible. The whole point of a view is that it is a view to a table or grouping of tables, ie. it must show the data that matches the view.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

What you could do is create another table called GoodsView and add a trigger to it to INSERT into Goods table and DELETE from GoodsView afterwards.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsqlp%2Frbafysqltrig.htm

Comment: It is possible. You just need your database system to support being able to make changes through a view that aren't then visible through that view